# How to to change the script arguments from perl debugger

Tags: perl, debugging, command-line-arguments

I'm debugging a perl script with a lot of command-line arguments.

Is it possible to restart the execution of the script (using the R command of perl debugger) using a different set of arguments?

Since I've got a lot of breakpoints and watches defined I don't want to exit the debugger and restart it with the new args...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a breakpoint at the start, restart it with R, and define the `@ARGV` you want in the debugger.